# Why does this error keep popping up when I install my app on AIDE?

Tags: xml, packageinstaller, aide

I am new to AIDE and am still learning but after I added a app icon it started crashing and it never has done this before, also here is my code for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Simple.myapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/iid_clt"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a crashlog?

Comment: To my knowladge I don't think so but the package installer crashes every time I attempt to install it, also I'm using AIDE on mobile device, I dont know if that could affect it or not.

Answer (score 1):

On code you set package="com.Simple.myapp" and picture shows different package name, set the package name that corresponds to the aide project